# How to check whether the mixer system is initialized in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame, text-to-speech

I have some code that needs to know whether the mixer system in Pygame is initialized so it can know when to exit it, as at the moment Pygame doesn't seem to be exiting properly. I have a text-to-speech program in Python that I'm currently trying to get to work on every operating system, as before it relied on Windows Media Player. I'm trying to use Pygame to achieve this purpose, however it does not close Pygame properly after using it the second time. When it loads the .mp3 file for the first time it will successfully exit Pygame and allow the program to delete the file, but if the user opts to try again and make another text-to-speech, it will re-initialize Pygame, write the file, open and then play the file. After the file has finished playing it will try to exit Pygame, however Pygame does not close properly and the program is unable to delete the .mp3 file as it is currently in use.

```
import os
import time
import sys
import getpass
import pip
from contextlib import contextmanager


my_file = "Text To Speech.mp3"
username = getpass.getuser()


@contextmanager
def suppress_output():

    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout


def check_and_remove_file():

    if os.path.isfile(my_file):
        os.remove(my_file)


def input_for_tts(message):

    try:

        tts = gTTS(text = input(message))
        tts.save('Text To Speech.mp3')
        audio = MP3(my_file)
        audio_length = audio.info.length
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(my_file)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep((audio_length) + 0.5)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        pygame.mixer.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        check_and_remove_file()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        check_and_remove_file()
        print("\nGoodbye!")
        sys.exit()


with suppress_output():

    pkgs = ['mutagen', 'gTTS', 'pygame']
    for package in pkgs:
        if package not in pip.get_installed_distributions():
            pip.main(['install', package])


import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from gtts import gTTS
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


check_and_remove_file()


input_for_tts("Hello there " + username + ". This program is\nused to output the user's input as speech.\nPlease input something for the program to say: ")


while True:

    try:

        answer = input("\nDo you want to repeat? (Y/N) ").strip().lower()
        if answer in ["n", "no", "nah", "nay", "course not"] or "no " in answer or "nah " in answer or "nay " in answer or "course not " in answer:
            check_and_remove_file()
            sys.exit()
        elif answer in ["y", "yes", "yeah", "course", "ye", "yea", "yh"] or "yes " in answer or "yeah " in answer or "course " in answer or "ye " in answer or "yea " in answer or "yh " in answer:
            input_for_tts("\nPlease input something for the program to say: ")
        else:
            print("\nSorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again with either Y or N.")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        check_and_remove_file()
        print("\nGoodbye!")
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if `pygame.mixer` is initialised, all you need to do is `pygame.mixer.get_init()` which will return the currently playing audio's data, unless it is uninitialised, in which case it will return `None`.

Source: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_init

Comment: though, I would much rather just declare a flag for it being initialised or not so I can know if an audio device is plugged in or not (if you try to initialise the mixer when no audio output is enabled, then it will raise a pygame.error exception).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I simply added a `try-except` when initializing it so that if it does raise `pygame.error`, it will tell the user that the code cannot complete and exit. I need `pygame.mixer.get_init()` so that the code knows whether or not it needs to close exit `pygame.mixer` when trying to delete a file that is used by it.